# How to use GCC extension to tell if overloaded method is overridden

Tags: c++, gcc, overloading, virtual-functions, pointer-to-member

It is explained [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Bound-member-functions.html) that gcc gives an extension thats takes a pointer to object and a pointer to virtual method and resolves the dynamic dispatch giving a free function pointer. It is unclear to me how to best do this when the virtual function is overloaded. I have some example code below.

[coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e78fce637180949)

```
#include <memory>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct B{ 
    virtual void f(){cout<<"b\n";}
    virtual void f() const {}//this makes things more interesting, can no longer use (F)&B::f, would need extra cast (F)(PTM)&B::f
    bool overridesf(){
        constexpr void (B::*ptm)()=&B::f;
        using PTM = decltype(ptm);
        using F = void (*)(B*);
        auto thisF = (F)(this->*ptm);
        auto notBaseF = (F)(PTM)&B::f;
        auto baseF = (F)(B().*ptm);//can simply use (F)&B::f when no overload is present
        B b;
        //below, all print b when `this` is a B
        thisF(this);//c when `this` is a C
        thisF(&b);//c when `this` is a C
        baseF(this);//b when `this` is a C
        baseF(&b);//b when `this` is a C
        notBaseF(this);//c when `this` is a C
        notBaseF(&b);//c when `this` is a C
        //return thisF!=notBaseF; //wrong: is false when this is a c
        return thisF!=baseF; //works correctly: true when this is a c
    }
};
struct C:B{
    void f()override{cout<<"c\n";}
};

int main() {
    auto b=make_unique<B>();
    cout<<b->overridesf()<<endl;
    b=make_unique<C>();
    cout<<b->overridesf();
}
```

I am interested in seeing if a object has overridden the first nonconst `f`, and I have created a function `overridesf` to do this. The idea is to do the dynamic dispatch on `this` to get a function pointer (`thisF`) and compare this function pointer to what we get if we do dynamic dispatch with an object that is known not to override f (`baseF`).

In fact, if `f` is not overloaded, then we can get the `baseF` function pointer simply with the expression `(F)&B::f`. However, if `f` is overloaded, this expression becomes ambiguous and we would have to do `(F)(PTM)&B::f`, where the PTM cast resolves the overload ambiguity. But (I think) the expression `(F)(PTM)&B::f` isn't a direct cast of a PMF constant (because of the intermediate cast), so the part about the direct conversion at the end of the linked page doesn't apply and you need an object (in my case `B()`).

I have two questions. First is there a better way to get `baseF`? If the interface has many pure virtual functions then it would be annoying to create a derived class which overrides all the pure virtuals (but of course not `f`) in order to construct an object to get `baseF`.

Another question is what is going on with `notBaseF` which is defined by the expression `(F)(PTM)&B::f`. Presumably this is undefined behavior, but is there an explanation for why the behavior of `notBaseF(&b)` is determined by the dynamic type of `this`?

Comment: From your question I understand that you want to get the function (`f`) of the base class, even if the function is overridden. And you want this to check whether it is overriden. Is that so? If yes why? Which use case needs such a method?

Comment: @JörgBrüggmann The goal is to tell if a specific overloaded virtual function has been overridden. If the base implementation is empty, this could allow for optimization where the virtual function is never called. The way I was trying to tell if function is overridden is to do the dynamic dispatch to get a free function pointer and see if it resolves to the same function pointer you get if you do the static dispatch. The dynamic dispatch works, but I don't know a good way to get the static dispatch to work.

Comment: Don't use [buggy ill-conceived GCC extensions](https://godbolt.org/z/49fdbEYP9).

Answer (score 0):

**Recap**

OK, as I understand you want to save the time for the access of the vtable ("dynamic dispatch") - in case of the function is not overriden. In order to do that you are going to apply a dynamic method like in `overridesf` - which would take even more time.

**Answer**

There is no method (to determine whether the function has been overriden) that is faster than the vtable access. I have no proof, but the reasons below. If this is correct then an optimisation like this is impossibe.

**Why?**

A vtable access would need the access of of one more address indirection - probably be just one CPU cycle. A dynamic method to determine whether the function has been overriden would need the access of two addresses and a comarison at least.

**A way out**

First determine how much time the dynamic dispach needs and how much time the functions itself need (nett) and whether an optimisation is worth it. If the overhead is only 10% then you would gain 10% if you find a static access method.

**Static dispatch**

If the optimisation for static dispatch is really worth it then don't use a dynamic method but a static method. Make use of the callers knowledge who may know which function has to be called. Templates can help to achieve that.

Comment: The context is that you have a loop that gets iterated over very many times and inside the loop (among other things) you have a vector of pointers to the base class where you call the virtual method on each object in the vector. I want to avoid adding an object to this vector if it doesn't override.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work if we pull the `auto notBaseF = (F)(PTM)&B::f;` out from the function body directly into the class definition, so that `notBaseF` becomes a static member. It seems when the ptm to function pointer conversion is done in the method, and the conversion is of the form `(F)(expr)`, where `expr` is a pointer to member valued expression not of the form &Class::ptmName, then the vtable of `this` is used to do the dispatch. However if this expression appears directly in the class definition to define a static member, then the dispatch is done the way I expected. The following code illustrates how `this` governs the dynamic dispatch when the ptm to function pointer is done in a member function.

https://godbolt.org/z/T4a37KjM3